# use parameters in conditional command in zk framework

Tags: command, arguments, conditional-statements, zk, zul

I'm triying to use a conditional @command with an argument passed with Executions.createComponents, this is my java code:

```
Map data = new HashMap();
data.put("isFromHere", true);
modal = (Window) Executions.createComponents("root/to/window", null, data);
modal.doModal();
```

And in my zul page I'm trying to do this:

```
<button label="Save" onClick="@command(arg.isFromHere ? 'save' : 'not')" />
```

But every time arg.isFromHere is returning false, like the argument is not passed. But if I do this:

```
<button if="${arg.isFromHere}" label="Save" onClick="@command('save'" />
```

That does work fine! What means the arguments are getting to the zul page, but not working on conditional commands, Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has all to do with the lifecycle of the binder.
`@Command` and `${arg.xxx}` are on different lifecycle.

[Read this documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Advanced/Pass_Arguments_to_Include_Component) and see your solution in it.

Solution for you :

### VM :

```
private boolean fromHere;

@Init
public void init(@ExecutionArgParam("isFromHere") boolean fromHere){
    this.fromHere = fromHere;
}

public boolean isFromHere() {
    return fromHere;
}
```

### zul :

```
<button label="Save" onClick="@command(vm.fromHere ? 'save' : 'not')" />
```